# How to download PDF in Jmeter Distributed Remote Testing on remote server?

Tags: pdf, jmeter, distributed-testing

I have designed a jmeter script to download PDF using 'Save response to a file' listener.It is working when I executed in local both in GUI and non GUI mode and the PDF is downloaded.But when im trying to run the same script in Distributed remote testing using client(windows 7) and server(windows 7) on the same subnet,unknown and plain files are getting downloaded instead of the the PDF file.
I have given folder path of the server in the Listener.Is there any other way to download the actual PDF instead of those unknown file.

thanks in advance :)

Comment: I will give you this caution.  It sounds like you want to create write permissions for Jmeter to write the resulting data to your web server.  That is a high-risk operation..

Comment: Hi , any feedback on answer? thx

Comment: As suggested added mode=Standard both in user.properties and in jmeter.properties in the client machine but there is no change.The same unknown files and plain files are getting downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

In distributed testing, jmeter uses StrippedBatch mode which strips response data when sending response to controller.

So you need to switch mode to One that does not strip like Standard:

- https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/trunk/bin/jmeter.properties#L758

So add to user.properties:

> mode=Standard

See also:

- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html 
  Paragraph 15.4

Comment: As suggested added mode=Standard both in user.properties and in jmeter.properties in the client machine but there is no change.The same unknown files and plain files are getting downloaded.